# MVC Routing access path

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am quite new to MVC. I am facing a problem with routing right now. My project URL is /account/Create.  I can access controller and do my stuff for Create, but
I need to access /account controller because I need to write code in that level.

/account/create - I can access the code this level
/account - dont know how to access this controller

**Project Stucture:**
Sample Project

- Controler
- Model
- View

What am I supposed to change in the following code?

```
//global.asax.cs
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } //Parameter defaults
    );
}
```

Comment: not sure what you want to achieve

Comment: It does not sound like you have any requirement that would cause you to change your default routes in `global.asax`.  Do you already have an Account controller?  Do a global find on the string 'class AccountController'

Comment: what you want actually?you can't access only the controller. you have to pass the action method like controller="Account", action="someaction" like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/account/create` is accessing code in the Account controller.  `Create` has to be a method on the Account controller (unless you modify the default routes).  Any public method you define on the account controller is accessible via `/account/method` URL.  Based on the route you posted, going to /account URL is going to call the account controller Index method:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    **new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }** // Parameter defaults
);
```

That **action = "Index"** part above is defining what the default method on the account controller is, so going to /account URL is equivalent in this case to /account/index URL

And I just noticed that you spelled account wrong in the question, not sure if that may be your issue ;)

---

Update

Not sure if this is what you're after, but if you need to write code at the /Account level you can do this in the constructor of the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you substantially customize MVC, then controllers correspond to classes derived from Controller in mvc, and actions correspond to methods on those controllers.

What are you trying to achieve when you say you can't access the controller /Account?

The controller is only a container for Actions so you need to specify an Action. Of course, you can have a default Action in case an action isn't specified. That is specified in default the route above. It's called Index